# Updating users alternate email address

Tags: smartsheet-api

Context: I am looking to migrate SSO from one domain using Okta to the new domain in Azure. I am looking to update the alternate email address for all the users with their new domain email address. I know there is a bulk update option via GUI but this requires validating the domain in Smartsheet UI. Since the new domain already has an instance of Smartsheet in their Azure, I'm not sure if validating the domain for a second instance will have a negative impact. So now I am exploring options with API. I'm a beginner to API's so not sure where to start.

Has anyone updated alternate email in bulk via API?

I have got the API token, but not sure where to start with the calls.

Comment: Hi Andrew -- if the answer below sufficiently addresses your question, can you please mark the answer as "Accepted"? Doing so will make others more likely to benefit from this info in the future. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, the Smartsheet API doesn't support updating the `alternateEmail` property of a `User` object -- not for a single user, not for multiple users (in bulk). So you'll need to use the Smartsheet UI to update alternate email addresses -- since it's not currently possible to do it via API.

FYI, this thread in the [Smartsheet Community](https://community.smartsheet.com) contains feedback about the exact situation you're trying to address: https://community.smartsheet.com/discussion/70468/bulk-updating-all-users-with-alternate-emails.